# Issues with Regex spaces and letters

Tags: regex

I need help with REGEX please.
The 4 and 5 lignes are fine.
But the first, 2nd and 3rd I don't want the "t" be matched.

I tried a lot of things but didn't worked unfortunatly.
So here is the link of what I did :
www.regexr.com/39rtb

/!\ Click the link to see what I see :p

```
\bt^(t\u0027)|(\bt)

No I don't
just t'oyota
just test
No I don t
t
```

/!\ I need a code for the 2sd line and an other for the last ! (last line is a t with nothing else !)

Thanks

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: I only see three lines. Please consider to update your question with the pattern and example, because links might change and then nobody could ever understand what you have been asking, when coming to this question later.

Comment: Sorry I add the code and updated link

Comment: In which language do you want to use this regex?

Comment: What pattern are you trying to match?

Comment: Hum I don't know, it is for a plugin so the file is .txt !

Comment: I have updated the file on the website ! I'm trying to match a single "t" with nothing else ! fore example : "t" or "hey t no" but I don't want to match this : "test don't"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to match a single `t`, assuming your flavor lets you use this syntax, you can enforce the `t` to be surrounded by whitespace or nothing else like so:

```
(?<=\s|^)t(?=\s|$)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nC0nC9/1)

This makes use of lookaround expressions.

---

The splitted version (assuming `(?m)` - if it doesn't work then try to prepend `(?m)` to each pattern):

```
(?!^t$)(?<=\s|^)t(?=\s|$)
```

And:

```
^t$
```

But it doesn't make much sense to separate these cases using regexes. You'd be better off doing the check in your language.

Comment: How can I do with all letters but "a" ?

Comment: @to175 replace the `t` in the pattern with `[b-zB-Z]`, or something more fancy like `(?!a)\p{L}` if you need Unicode support (like accented letters)

Comment: Thx, @Lucas Trzesniewski  can I have 2 codes ? (one with all without a single "t" and the other with only a single "t")

Comment: @to175 you should do that from your code rather than from regexes.

Comment: I don't understand what do you say... (I'm French) I have edited the end of main message (the question) @Lucas Trzesniewski !

Comment: I can't do any, there is no code only regex ! I can only write regex in the file...

Comment: Thanks, but the first one block the "t" without any else in the string :(

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you asked for? I think I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Ok, I want a code for "t" (nothing else in string) and an other one for "hey a t alone"

Comment: Did you understand now ? @LucasT  :)

Comment: @to175 [First pattern](http://regex101.com/r/pW3oR1/1), [Second pattern](http://regex101.com/r/dX3eU2/1). What's wrong with these?

Comment: Yep problem with the leng one @LucasT In fact there is an full example : [link](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/pwnfilter/pages/sample-regex-rules/)

Comment: This doesn't work : match (?!^[b-zB-Z]$)(?<=\s|^)[b-zB-Z](?=\s|$)/gm

Comment: Try `(?m)(?!^.$)(?<=\s|^)[b-zB-Z](?=\s|$)` without this `/gm` stuff. If that doesn't work... well I won't be able to help anymore since I don't know that tool.